# Limit visit by IP for given seconds

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, time

I'm using CakePHP and I need to limit page views on a specific page for a small, random number of seconds. I write the code however, sometimes, even if it shouldn't, the blocking trigger is tricked.

```
$site_seconds = "100";          
$get15 = $site_seconds * 5 / 100;
$ip_session = $credits_one - $get15;
$ip_session_time = round($ip_session);
```

I use this so I get a lower number than the actually visiting time, it was created to avoid errors like the one I have, not really helpful.
So if we got 100 seconds, we take in count 95 seconds.

```
    $conditions_check = array(
        'date >=' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-$ip_session_time SECONDS")),
        'user' => $user_id,
        'value1' => $ip,
        'type' => '3'
    );

       /// we check if the condition has any rows 
        if ($this->Log->hasAny($conditions_check)){ 
           // If found I send a private message to the user
             $this->Log->set('date', date('Y-m-d H:i:s')); // time here is only for ordering when displayed to user
             $this->Log->set('user', $user_id);
             $this->Log->set('value1', $ip);
             $this->Log->set('value2', "No credits received for this visit. To many conditions from same IP.");
             $this->Log->set('value3', "1");
             $this->Log->set('type', '4');
             $this->Log->save();
            }else{
           // The code runs
            }
```

I tried to use `strtotime(*now*);` but it was even worse, the error showed up every time, with this code, maybe every 2 minutes.

Comment: What is the value of `$credits_one`? Also set an integer at `$site_seconds` instead of a string: `$site_seconds = 100;`

Comment: The value of `$credits_one` varies between 10 and 120 seconds. When I define i use `$credits_one = $site['Site']['surfsec'];` , Is that counted as a string ?

Comment: I add `$seconds_int = intval($credits_one);` but the error persists.

Comment: Your script is not called twice because of any reason?

Comment: Negative, the code runs at the beginning of the page, it's only accessible on post method, through a costume C# browser. The page receives the POST data after $site_seconds hits 0 in the C# browser.

Comment: https://github.com/UseMuffin/Throttle

Comment: Looks good but I got it working after all, also I use CakePHP 2.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized where is my mistake, I set the time, but when I check if the user is visiting too fast I check with the new timer, and in case the number is higher than the old one, the error triggers. 
A way to fix it is to insert a new time value, when the IP should be released.

Thanks @Stefan for your help.